# Drop all the columns after a particular column

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-polars

Suppose, I am reading a csv with hundreds of columns.

Now, I know that after a particular column say `'XYZ'` all the columns are junk.

I want to keep all the columns from the beginning till column `'XYZ'` and drop all the columns after column `'XYZ'`.

In pandas, I may do something like:

```
df.iloc[:, :df.columns.get_loc('XYZ') + 1]
```

What could be an efficient way in polars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slicing with `[:]` solution works for eager evaluation ([`DataFrame`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html)), but as far as I know it doesn't really work for [`LazyFrame`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/index.html).

If you want to be able to use lazy evaluation, you can just use [`DataFrame.select()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.select.html):

```
# prepare the data
df = pl.LazyFrame({
    'ABC': [1,2,3],
    'DEF': [4,5,6],
    'XYZ': [7,8,9],
    'garbage1': [10,11,12],
    'garbage2': list('abc')
})
df.sink_csv('test.csv')
```

now we can scan it:

```py
df = pl.scan_csv('test.csv')
df.select(df.columns[:df.columns.index('XYZ')+1]).collect()

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ ABC ┆ DEF ┆ XYZ │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I'm not sure, however, how efficient polars can filter out columns which don't have to be returned, cause they still have to be read from the file.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the column exists, you could proceed similarly to pandas:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'ABC': [1,2,3], 'DEF': [4,5,6],
                   'XYZ': [7,8,9], 'GHI': [10,11,12]})

out = df[:, :df.columns.index('XYZ')+1]
# or 
out = df[:, :df.find_idx_by_name('XYZ')+1]
```

Or, shorter (and more efficient):

```
out = df[:, :'XYZ']
```

Output:

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ ABC ┆ DEF ┆ XYZ │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 4   ┆ 7   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: great solution btw. But is there no way in python to control the number of columns bein read in? instead of reading the whole dataframe just to subset it afterwards. I know in R one could use `readr::read_csv(file, col_select = 1:XYZ)` ie the columns are selected during reading and not After being read

Comment: @Onyambu not to my knowledge for pandas. Although you could first read just the header, identify the columns to keep and read again with the column list. Not sure for polars.

Comment: @Onyambu If [`.scan_csv`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html#polars.scan_csv) is used instead then Polars will only project columns that are selected/used.

Comment: @jqurious could you please include a solution with that? It will satisfy the question as OP is interested in reading the columns upto XYZ.  Perhaps thats the way to go with this question